# I want to change my ; semicolon to , coma in windows form properties in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

This is the properties window and as you can see in the highlighted line the semicolon between the numbers and I want to change it to comma as default.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why? What is the benefit of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My VS uses `,` rather than `;` for Size etc. If you click start, type *control*, open control panel, search *region*, open it and click **additional**, what does your window look  like?

Mine looks like:

[image]

If I change "list separator" to `;` then my VS looks like yours (after I restart it)

Comment: restart you VS instance for the changes to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man, it worked.  because I'm using color picker a lot and the format is always with a comma so this was very helpful.